# Just 2 images on a window loaded using DirectX10...But how?

Tags: c++, directx, directx10

I am a beginner to DX and I have tried looking everywhere for something very similar to this concept but can't find anything.

I just want two rectangles on a window.

Rectangle 1 : on some x,y with some width and height with background as a PNG image
Rectangle 2 : on some x,y with some width and height with background as a PNG image

And one other thing. I am trying to make it so that the image doesn't resize as I resize the window as this makes the pictures really blurry as they get bigger.

I know this is not the type of question that stack likes, but if you can give me some example that does this, I would be very delighted.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, why DirectX10? If all you want to do is 2D there are more simple API such as SDL that can do exactly what you're asking. SDL tutorial site: http://lazyfoo.net/

Comment: Because DirectX isn't meant to be 'quick and dirty', there will be a lot of setup required to do anything with it.  If you clarified why you want to do it that way it will help people answer your question.  Is it because you want to learn DirectX and you think that is a good starting challenge?  Or is that the final product you need, and there's some reason unstated why you want or need to do that in DirectX?

Comment: @TASagent It simply because I want to learn DirectX and I think that putting 2 basic images will teach me some basics and then I will proceed to learn different aspects. I know people have different strategies to learn, but this something I want to try out.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero I know you can do this various other libraries, but I have always been interested in how games are made and I would like to try by just seeing an example.

Comment: @M. Dudley I have tried the tutorial here: http://takinginitiative.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/directx10-tutorial-9-the-geometry-shader/ But I am confused as to why you need to use a Geometry Shader to draw a Sprite? Can't you do it any other way? I come from a heavy Java 2D background and I there all you really have to do is set the location and source image and you can paint directly on.

Comment: That explains it using the geometry shader because it is a geometry shader tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you expressed interest in learning how to use DirectX, just in the context of your specific challenge, I have to direct you to an outside source.

'Teach me how to use DirectX' is a bit outside the scope of what this is meant for, and any complete answer would be far too long, besides.

For decent intro tutorials, I recommend: http://rastertek.com/tutindex.html

By tutorial 5 you'll have the tools you need to be able to complete your request.  If, at that point, you still need help or are confused about something, that is a good time to post a question here about it.

The tutorials create an engine that *works*, though it needs a bit of redesign to be useful for more than learning.  Regardless, that is a good place to start.

Comment: I will go ahead and do the tutorial, however I am confused on concept. What is the difference between Sprites and regular old Textures? Just to get an idea.

Comment: A sprite is a 2D image or animation.  A texture is the color information that is applied to polygons.  In the case of an unanimated sprite, the texture is applied to a Quad (a square made of two triangles), and makes the sprite.  In the case of an animated sprite, several textures are used to give the appearance of animation.  Additionally, textures can be used on 3D objects as well, in which case it is the color data (or other data) that gets dumped onto the faces of a 3d object.

Comment: With that being said, in the tutorial above, what is the benefit of rendering the sprite using a Geometry Shader?

Comment: The Geometry Shader is an Extra, Optional step that can be inserted between the (somewhat) mandatory Vector and Pixel shader steps.  It has a variety of uses, like the tutorial says for particle systems and tessellation, but understanding how it works or is useful requires first knowing about what the Vector Shader and Pixel Shaders are, something covered in a very early step of the tutorial.

Comment: When you create a vertex array, it is made of floating point values. Are those values actual pixel positions on the screen? Or do you have to multiply by the world x view x projection matrices to get the screen pixels? If so, what are vertex array positions relative to? And are there as many world, view, and projection matrices as there the number of models? I know I have asked you a lot on a comment, but I do sincerely thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No, it's fine.  I don't mind answering questions when you're obviously putting forth effort to learn.  Technically: it can be anything you want.  Some 2D rendering engines just pass quads to the Vertex Shader already in screenspace (-1 to 1 on both axes).  Usually you might do with with 2D menus you're drawing on top of the screen, either passing in quads that are in Pixel Space (0 to Resolution) or Screen Space.  Largely, the point of the vertex shader is to have a place to convert local coordiantes to screen space, by passing in a World, Projection, and then View matrix.

Comment: The World Matrix will 'move' the polygon to where it actually is in the world, the Projection Matrix will apply a perspective transformation on the world, and then the View matrix will push everything into Screen Space.  Though all that matters is that the coordinates be in Screen space when the Vertex shader is done with them.  If you're doing a pass-through vertex shader, you literally take In a coordinate in screen space, then return that same coordinate, still in screen space.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but there is still a gray space that I am not sure about regarding this. **Question 1.** You said the the _screenspace_ is (-1 to 1 on both axes). What do you mean by that? Like 1.0f or -1.0f? **Question 2.** Is screen space different than _screen pixel_? **Question 3.** Do we have one global world/view/projection matrices or do we have one for each model?

Comment: Yeah, Screen space is generally a float from -1 to 1.  Anything outside of that range isn't rendered on the screen.  Things can be outside of that, and they're simply not drawn.  I'm not sure what you mean screen pixel, but I was thinking of pixel space as 0->XREZ,0->YREZ.  The world matrix will always be per-object.  It includes position, scale, and rotation.  The View matrix is based on the camera, and the projection matrix takes it from Camera to Screen space.  So, Your World (or Model) matrix is per-object, your view is per camera, and your proj doesn't really change much.

Comment: This all makes sense now. And one more question and I'll stop bothering you for now. How do I create the world matrix and set it's position, scale, etc? Thank you again.

Comment: Creating the world matrix and setting position, scale, etc is actually dependent on how you've set everything else up and defined your objects in the first place.  I would recommend taking a look at how it's done in the tutorial I posted before as an example.  Just follow it from the Shader class files.